I have built an extension, I want to toggle On/Off so that it will turn on/off the extension. How can i do that?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const toggleSwitch = document.getElementById('toggleSwitch');
    const toggleStatus = document.getElementById('toggleStatus');

    // Set initial state of toggle switch
    chrome.storage.sync.get('enabled', function(data) {
        const isEnabled = data.enabled;
        toggleSwitch.checked = isEnabled;
        toggleStatus.textContent = isEnabled ? 'Extension is currently ON' : 'Extension is currently OFF';
    });

    // Toggle extension state when switch is clicked
    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const enabled = toggleSwitch.checked;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'enabled': enabled }, function() {
            toggleStatus.textContent = enabled ? 'Extension is currently ON' : 'Extension is currently OFF';
            updateExtensionState(enabled);
        });

        if (!enabled) {
            chrome.management.setEnabled('jgljfcgfldbadoohflpjbheloooggmdm', false);
        }
    });

    // Update extension state based on toggle switch
    function updateExtensionState(enabled) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ command: "toggleExtension", enabled: enabled });
    }
});

Here I got this error

Uncaught TypeError: chrome.management.setEnabled is not a function

can anyone help me to build on/off button for my extension?
solution code for on/off toggle button that turns on/off my extension in google chrome


To use this API you need to add "management" in "permissions" in manifest.json. 2) setEnabled disables the entire extension, so it can't run again. 3) Toggle the content script as shown here.

